# SSRS Multi-Value Parameter Not Filtering

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a few `Parameters` that I am trying to set based off of results that the user selects, but when I select from my Multi-Value `Parameter` my report errors with `Failed to evaluate the FilterValues of the DataSet 'DST_MyThirdDataSet'`

I have my first `DataSet` called `DST_MyFirstDataSet` which is used to create a list `Parameter` called `Parameter1`.

My second `DataSet` called `DST_MySecondDataSet` is filtered based from what is selected in `Parameter1`. My filter looks like this:

```
Expression [DataSet1Id] Integer = CInt(Parameters!Parameter1.Value)
```

This is what I use for my second `Parameter` called `Parameter2` which is a Multi-Value parameter. This seems to be working correctly.

My third `DataSet` is called `DST_MyThirdDataSet` which I have set up to be filtered based off of what is selected in `Parameter2`. My filter looks like this:

```
Expression [DataSet2Id] Integer In CInt(Parameters!Parameter2.Value)
```

Everywhere I have looked online seems to support what I have (using the `In` Operator and using `Parameters!Parameter2.Value`), but i still seem to be getting this silly error.

Does anyone see where I could be going wrong here?

**EDIT**

It seems to work if instead of converting the `Parameter` to a `Integer`, I convert the `Field` to a `String`, but why cant I do it the way that I originally had?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `Parameters!Parameter2.Value` is actually an array because it is a multi-select parameter. So you're trying to convert an array to an integer and that won't work.

You can even access individual array elements by doing `Parameters!Parameter2.Value(1)` or the number of items in the array `Parameters!Parameter2.Count` ([more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd255264.aspx))

I would recommend setting the data types of your parameters to an integer if they are supposed to be an integer. That way you can avoid having to do any conversions that might fail.
[image: parameter data type configuration]

Comment: Thank you! You answer did solve my issue. However, I would just like to clarify that `Parameters!Parameter2.Value` does work. Even though you are correct in saying that it is an array, that is okay because I was using the `IN` operator which would allow a lookup with in an "array" of values. What ended up solving my issue was setting the parameter Data Type to an Integer. Thanks again!

Comment: You were using the in operator on `Cint(Parameter...)` the cint function doesn't return an array and doesn't work on each value in an array. So it isn't doing what you thought it was.